# Azure DevOps - Store build/release variables from powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

> Original question
>
> Is it possible to store the response from a REST API call in a
>   variable and use it in the downstream jobs?

Question update:

I want to store the resolved value through a PowerShell script, and make it accessible through out the next stages. I have setup a script like this:

```
$slot = &"c:\temp\GetSlot.exe" 2>&1
Write-host "resolved:" $slot
Write-host "init value output:" $(currentslot)

Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=currentslot;isOutput=true;]$slot")
Write-host "updated value output:" $(currentslot)
```

Along with a variable, to make it accessible throug the $(currentslot) in aditional stages. Its configured like this:

[image]
Stages:
[image]

The value from the executions is being set into the $slot variable, but the variable is not getting updated, what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you would use regular way of doing so:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=containerName]$containerName"
                                            ^             ^ variable content (string)
                                            ^ variable name in downstream tasks
```

you can also use yaml to share variables between phases (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/blob/master/docs/pipelines/process/multiple-phases.md)

create\update release through api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0 (it has variables property)

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41, I updated the question - cant quite get this to work.

Comment: define `next stages`?

Comment: Updated question with stage definition.

Comment: ok, that wont work, it will only work in the same build\stage. you would need to use ADO rest api to create\update those variables

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I think i am going to determine the the value on each stage to keep it simple. But thanks for clarifying the possibilities for me.